Kosinki exercise: when is $S^{2k-1}$ fibered by $(k-1)$-spheres over $S^k$?
The following is, verbatim, the Exercise from p. 160 of Kosinski's "Differential Manifolds" (2007 Dover edition):
Exercise: Show that $S^{2k-1}$ is fibered by $(k-1)$-spheres over $S^k$ if and only if there exists a $(k-1)$-connected closed $2k$-manifold $M$ with $H_k(M)=\mathbb{Z}$.
My understanding of Kosinski's conventions is that here he is talking about smooth fiber bundles with structure group $O(k)$, and that he is really referring to the standard smooth structure on these spheres (and, in particular, not to an exotic structure on $S^k$).
With that said, I believe the "if" implication can be proved as follows (with inspiration from the third exercise on p. 133): if such a fiber bundle exists, then take $E(2k)$ to be the total space of the associated disc bundle and $M=M(2k)$ to be the result of gluing a disc to $E(2k)$ along its boundary by a diffeomorphism.
Assuming I have not made a mistake, I am more confused about the remaining "only if" implication. If $M$ is as in the exercise, then by the proof of Theorem 6.2 on p. 160, I know that $M$ is obtained by diffeomorphically gluing a disc along its boundary to a $(2k,k)$-handlebody of genus $1$ (a $2k$-disc with a single $k$-handle attached).
I am hoping to establish the "only if" implication by proving that this $(2k,k)$-handlebody is a $k$-disc bundle over $S^k$ (so that its boundary $S^{2k-1}$ is fibered by $(k-1)$-spheres), but seem to be stuck.
Question: Is the statement of this exercise correct, and if so, how can I solve it? Also, is there a reference with a proof of this (seemingly important) exercise?
I am mainly asking about the "only if" implication (but would be happy to also have a sanity check about my proof of the "if" portion).
What I have tried: every result (I think) related to proving that something is a disc bundle from the first 160 pages of Kosinski's book. In particular, the results on pp. 105--106 initially looked promising, but I think I do not have enough control on the attaching map for the $k$-handle here. Proposition 11.2 on p. 115 also looked promising, but its assumption on the dimension seems off by one relative to what is needed. Another failed (?) attempt was in trying to somehow combine Theorem 7.3 on p. 108 with information on p. 118. I have also tried to combine the information on p. 118 with Theorem 4.4 on pp. 153--154, but don't see how to verify the relative homology assumption of that theorem (or why it should hold), but I think this may be my most promising current idea.
Thanks for any help!
